Having trouble installing an additional version of PHP on Debian docker image
I need a docker instance that is running PHP7.4, as well as PHP8.3. So I've started with a docker image:
FROM  --platform=linux/amd64 php:7.4-apache
This gets me Debian 11. Now, I follow the script at https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt exactly, which should add additional PHP versions into my apt sources. But when I try to install it:
sh-5.1# apt install php8.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package php8.3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php8.3' has no installation candidate

Everything looks like it's in the right place - what am I doing wrong? I've tried a lot of different things at this point but nothing gets me any further than this.

Configuring a container to run both 7.4 and 8.3 at the same time kinda defeats the point of using containers. Just use two containers?

@AlexHowansky almost agree, yes.  But, i can see some use cases for this.  Key is having 2 fpm processes, one 7.4 and one 8.3 , and pick my routes according to which microservice has been refactored.  Mostly for non-regression testing.

@YvesLeBorg Note the php:7.4-apache image referenced in the post doesn't use FPM, it uses the native module. And that 7.4 build is a custom PHP one, it's not the same as the 7.4 from the sury.org repo, so it doesn't hook into alternatives as nicely. You'd have to make some drastic changes to get two FPMs. You'd be better off starting with a Debian/Apache container that didn't have PHP at all, and then adding both 7.4 and 8.3 from sury. But even then it would be almost certainly be simpler to just use two containers.

Unfortunately I'm trying to simulate a legacy environment that uses both versions or I would do two containers.
